# request.body.split('&').each displays undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, metasploit

When I run the following part of my code the "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error appears.

```
if request and request.body
  print_status(request.body);
  request.body.split('&').each { |var|
    parts = var.split('=', 2)
    if parts.length != 2
      print_error("Weird, we got a var that doesn't contain an equals: #{parts.inspect}")
    else
      fln,fld = parts
      fld = Rex::Text.uri_decode(fld)
      if fln == "script"
        script = fld
      end
    end
  }
end
```

**Some tests with request.body:**

```
- ----------------------------------
- request.body.class: String
- request.body: script=test
- request.body.split('&'): ["script=test"]
- Sending
- ----------------------------------
- request.body.class: String
- request.body: script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B
- request.body.split('&'): ["script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B"]
- Sending
- ----------------------------------
- request.body.class: String
- request.body: script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B%3D
- request.body.split('&'): ["script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B%3D"]
- Exception handling request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
- ----------------------------------
- request.body.class: String
- request.body: script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B%5D
- request.body.split('&'): ["script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B%5D"]
- Exception handling request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
- ----------------------------------
- request.body.class: String
- request.body: script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B-
- request.body.split('&'): ["script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B-"]
- Exception handling request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
- ----------------------------------
- request.body.class: String
- request.body: script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B+
- request.body.split('&'): ["script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B+"]
- Exception handling request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Most special characters make the error occurs.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What is `request.body`? A string?

Comment: Is it really `request.body.split('&').each` line throwing an exception? I don't see the problem here, if `request.body.split('&')` is always a string.

Comment: request.body.split('&') return an array of 1 item. Yes, it is the only each on entire rb file.

Comment: It might be each defined somewhere else. Could you post your backtrace? (e.g. there might be `each` inside `Rex::Text.url_encode` method). Split is always returning an array, so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: There is no method url_encode inside Rex::Text. There is uri_encode / uri_decode. Check the sources: https://dev.metasploit.com/api/Rex/Text.html#uri_encode-class_method https://dev.metasploit.com/api/Rex/Text.html#uri_decode-class_method

Comment: I've tried to put an exception handler to backtrrace (with begin and rescue => e) but it doen't catch the excpetion. I don't know why.

Comment: You're right. The problem is not in this code. After execute this, there is the following calls:
  js = ::Rex::Exploitation::JSObfu.new %Q|
#{script}
  js.obfuscate
|
the problem is inside js.obfuscate method.
Exactly in this function: https://dev.metasploit.com/api/Rex/Exploitation/JSObfu.html#obfuscate_r-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to use `request.body.read` instead of `request.body`.

`ActionDispatch::Request.body` method is StringIO, refer to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-body

Comment: Displays Exception handling request: undefined method `read' for "script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B":String

Comment: if request.body is script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B it works, if it is script=alert%28%27ok%27%29%3B%3D it doens't work.

Comment: And in both cases it's type is string?

Comment: Yes, I've checked and in both cases request.body.class is a String.

Comment: Then your split should work and return array, I think. Can you provide more examples of return values from `request.body.split('&')`?